# Publish .cshtml views for RazorLight in .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, publish

All my code is [open source](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/tree/bug/fix-emails). Please feel free to browse around. I'm on the **bug/fix-emails** branch.

I am trying to publish some `.cshtml` files that are needed by [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) for sending an HTML email out. The `.cshtml` files sit here:

[image: location of .cshtml files in relation to project]

I have already referenced `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and in my `.csproj` I have:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="EmailTemplates\*.cshtml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Yet when I publish, I see no `EmailTemplates` folder and no `ForgotPassword.cshtml` and `Registration.cshtml`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"Yet when I publish, I see no EmailTemplates folder and no ForgotPassword.cshtml and Registration.cshtml."_  Could you share the screenshot of the result? I tested your project and published it to the folderProfile target, there is the EmailTemplates folder in OutputDirectory.

Comment: @XueliChen here is [the output](https://imgur.com/a/ZNNwIkl). Sorry for the delay, I only just saw your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, this is what I did in my `.csproj` to overcome this problem. VS will execute an `xcopy` command before publish, which it will copy the files into the `out` folder. This will then published together to the specific publish folder.

```
<Target Name="PrePublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(ProjectDir)Templates&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)Templates&quot; /S /F /I /R /Y" />
</Target>
```